# Strapi as a database

Tags: database, strapi

I have a quick question about Strapi. I use it quite a bit with Gatsby or Vue in CMS mode. But my question is, is it possible to store data from the front on Strapi (eg pseudo name, ...) in database mode. And thus be able to recover all that by the interface of Strapi? Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update data from a vue frontend and view it on Strapi.
[For example using GraphQL mutations](https://vue-apollo.netlify.app/guide/apollo/mutations.html)

But if you need transparent database connection;
No, I don't think it's possible.

What you are asking is Data transparency which is a feature of **Directus**.

https://docs.directus.io/guides/database.html#database-mirroring

Comment: Thank you for the links ans answer

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to store data of your Strapi application in other database like MySQL and PostgreSQL then you can follow below links.

- [MySQL](https://strapi.io/blog/configuring-strapi-mysql-database)
- [PostgreSQL](https://strapi.io/blog/postgre-sql-and-strapi-setup)